# jQuery - pull navigational focus to a particular link on page load

Tags: jquery, focus, pageload

As soon as a page loads, I want the focus to jump to a particular link, so hitting enter will 'click' it.

I've tried

`$('ul li a:first').focus();`

without luck, but I think I may be misinterpreting the usage of .focus().

Any advice appreciated!

:s

Comment: I think you have interpreted '.focus()' perfectly. Which browser did this not work in?

Comment: Perhaps your js is executed too early?  Did you put this into the jQuery document ready block?

Comment: the problem exactly! thanks for all replies. I had it almost at the end of the document but obviously not far down enough!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is almost right. You just miss `$(document).ready.`

To fix, use this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('ul li a:first').focus();
});
```

See example in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vMZpx/).

The problem is when jquery is called the page doesn't have that link yet.
With `$(document).ready.` you call jquery only when page is complete.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, though it's a little odd how it works (and I found this on the [jQuery `focus`](http://api.jquery.com/focus/) docs, and don't claim to understand *why* it works):

```
$(document).ready(
  function() {
    $("a:first").attr("tabindex",'-1').focus();
  }
  );
```

Demo at: [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/icodo4)

Comment: This has just really come in handy - it's great for giving focus to things that don't usually aquire focus, such as a div. Thanks David!